# Build Very Simple Minimalist Java Plugin Container

Tags: java, plugins, containers, modularity, loose-coupling

I'm working on an app where I'm in need of building a very small and minimal plugin container.

Below are the things I'm trying to achieve.

1. Application is divided into smaller plugins packaged as Jars.
2. Plugin container should get them and load all jars.
3. Each plugin should not interfere with other plugins and should run on it's own along with it's dependant libraries. Basically all plugins should be isolated at runtime.

I tried using OSGI container, but it adds high complexity. Also many of the third party libraries which are not compatible with OSGI creating problem which is taking lot of time to debug. Also checked out Spring Boot, JPF etc. and not very interested. So thought of using very small homegrown plugin framework.

I have no clue on how to do and where to start. Please anyone can point me in right direction where I can get detailed information on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: will the application needs UI ? It will be a web application? Or it will be a sort of daemon ?

Comment: Sounds like something you could realize with Docker + Kubernetes or the like. Not sure what exactly you want to do though tbh.

Comment: Application doesn't need UI. But all plugins should be able to interact with each other. Container should have a small service registry.

Comment: If your goal is to keep everything minimalist for the plugin developer (but don't mind using a more complex framework as your plugin platform), OSGI can be a good option. For example, a few years ago I used Apache Karaf for a modular web app - all the plugin developer had to do was to implement some service interfaces and drop their jar with (non-osgi) libraries in a folder where Karaf automatically runs the jars as OSGI bundles.

Answer (score 1):

If you truely want something minimalistic, have a look at Java's [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html) class.
Here's a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html).